# Javascript charting and link-able labels

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Any ideas of a JavaScript charting library that allows me to use data labels that I can double as HTML links? I need to be able to create radar charts, specifically, and other charts would be a plus.

Comment: I like gRaphael - looks like there's some [third party support](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=raphael+radar) for radar graphs.  It can certainly do the data labels, HTML links, interactivity, canvas support and DOM tie-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using Flot charting library with a plugin that enables radar graphing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the charting capabilities in extjs 4 - http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/

There are definitely hooks for events / renderers on the data labels.

Comment: Would have loved to use this, but we can't use GPL licensed products on our software projects.